# Unexpected result while assigning value to a character array in dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following program is showing unexpected result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* num1;
    num1 = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    num1 = "38462879";
    printf("%s\n",num1);
    num1[0]='5';
    printf("%s\n",num1);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it to print the given string and then print the given string with the first letter replaced by 5 instead of 3 in the next line.

But it is printing the given string in first line and then the program is not going ahead.

Can you please help??

Comment: Changing code after commands or answers were given should be avoided.

Comment: You first allocate dynamic memory. Then you throw away that address and replace it with the address of an immutable string literal. That is a memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying

```
 num1 = "38462879";
```

you're essentially

- Overwriting the allocated pointer to the memory (memory leak)
- Making `num1` point to a *string literal*. (illegal to attempt to modify the content)

Later your attempt to modify a part of that literal will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What you need instead is to use `strcpy()`, like

```
 strcpy (num1, "38462879");
```

That said, couple of general suggestion:

- for a hosted environment, `int main()` should at least be `int main(void)`.
- You must always check for the success of a function call (esp. library functions) before using the returned value.
- in C, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`, it's a redundant multiplier.

Comment: What is the problem in making `num1` point to a string literal? And why modifying a part of that literal is invoking undefined behaviour??

Comment: @Martund Because the C standard says so. I will add the relevant quotes, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign a constant string to num1, but use strcpy(): strcpy(num1, "whatever");

Comment: You can assign constant strings to char *. But you are right, because later num1[0] is modified.

Comment: `Do not assign a constant string to num1` why not? Some explanation needed.

Answer (score 0):

this is a character ,you can't allocate memory for one character and store a string it it , it only has space for one character . I think you meant `char *num1`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh it was `char num1` before edit. not `char* num1`

Comment: Now once it has been changed, this answer also should change, is not it?